# I have added Git plugin in Jenkins after that all my jobs are throwing exception stating failed to load

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

Before installing Git plugin in my Jenkins all my jobs were working properly. After installing the Git plugin, my Jenkin get restart and after that my jobs are not displaying in dashboard. When I check in system log, I found issue stating "Failed to load struct, Failed to load x job, Failed to load Y job..... And so on".

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Things not a helpdesk. [How to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Did you at least look in the logs for errors and what did it say?

Comment: Agreed with Ian, we will need more info like logs to assist on this forum.

Comment: Try uninstalling the Git plugin, to see if that at least fixes things.

Comment: Please provide some logs to look into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade Jenkins to the latest version. This will solve the problem.